# WebStorm editor endlessly cycles through "updating index"

Tags: webstorm

I've installed the WebStorm 2016.2 editor. I opened one file, and now whenever I make any changes the window for that file the editor cycles through the following states:

- When I modify the file a dialog with "Updating index" shows (with no cancel or other controls) running for about half a minute
- Then there is a progress bar at the bottom of the editor, "Indexing", which goes to completion, taking about another half minute
- After this any click on the file will repeat this cycle

I've tried invalidating the cache, restarting the editor, and also reverting any changes to the file, none of which makes a difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that I had accidentally excluded the file i was editing from the Webstorm project. When I undid that exclusion the problem went away.

I can only presume that Webstorm was detecting that the file hadn't been indexed, and therefore ran the indexer, but the exclusion meant it wasn't indexing the file. Thus the next time the file was touched it tried to run it again.